# My disc brake rotors have started to corrode. What can I do?

Tags: maintenance, mountain-bike, brakes

For the last two weeks, I was using my bike heavily in rainy weather. I was cycling during rain for hours. Now I noticed that the discs of my disc brakes started to corrode. What can I do now? Should I just clean them? If yes, how?

Comment: How much corrosion? Can you post a pic?

Comment: How do you get the rust off of automobile disks?

Comment: Discs corroding while you're riding in the rain mean that you're part of the tough stuff. 'Brakes are for cowards' and you don't overuse them, good! But some hard braking will clear the rust. At least it does on my motorbike.

Answer (score 5):

Generally, it will go away if you apply the brakes a bit (it will be a bit noisy at first, but after a few applications it will look as good as new), since the rust is likely only on the surface (this is one way to tell if a car has been not driven for a few days - rust spots appear on the brake discs, but they'll go away after a short trip around town). Otherwise, if its more serious, you can  try light sanding with sand paper / steel wool / wire brush or something similar and then cleaning the rotor with isopropanol.

It goes without saying, but, don't get oil on the brake rotors while cleaning it.